# jQuery returns checkboxes as all checked even if only one is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, checkbox

As per this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/AJwXV/2/) --

I have been going crazy trying to figure this out for last 48 hours.  Everything works except for the checkbox.  I included the isolated snippet of code that is causing the issue in this.

After I created boxes (pressing checkbox button) and finalize the form, I was successful in seeing `code` and was able to serialize checkboxes into `JSON` - but, I ended up getting 'on' for all checkboxes even though if only one of them is checked.

When I checked only one (first box) and other boxes unchecked, and clicked 'save', I get this as result:

`{"ck1":"on","ck2":"on","ck3":"on","submit1":"save"}`

What was it that threw the result off? Am I doing something wrong in this code?

A help would be appreciated in identifying the issue.
My goal is to see JSON in this format when I have first checkbox checked:

`{"ck1":"on","submit1":"save"}` or any format that you would suggest.

EDITED:

Find below the function I assinged to submit event:

```
 $('#form'+formnum).submit( function(e) {
e.preventDefault(e);
var data = {};

//Gathering the Data
$.each(this.elements, function(i, v){
        var input = $(v);
        data[input.attr("id")] = input.val();
 //delete data[button.attr("id")]; <-- cant' figure it out
//removeData[submit] <-- cant' figure it out
}); // end of $.each

var output =JSON.stringify(data);
$('#showurl').text(output);
}); //end of 'save' button function
```

JSFIDDLE: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/AJwXV/2/).

Comment: Even if you provide a Fiddle, you should post the relevant code **in the question itself**. Link-only questions and answers do not follow the site guidelines because become useless if the link breaks.

Comment: You want this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/AJwXV/3/ ?

Comment: Your checkbox is missing an id.

Comment: data[input.attr("id") || input.attr("name")]  should fix it

Comment: I'd suggest using serialize or serializeArray which would automagically solve this problem for you.

Comment: If you have to create everything using JS than try http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/AJwXV/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the value from the checkboxes, and the value is always the same regardless of the state of the checkbox.

Check the type of the element to get the state for checkboxes:

```
if (input.is(':checkbox')) {
  if (input.is(':checked')) {
    data[input.attr("id")] = input.val();
  }
} else {
  data[input.attr("id")] = input.val();
}
```

If you only want data from the checkboxes, you can just filter out the the checked checkboxes from start:

```
$(':checked', this).each(function(i, v){ data[v.id] = v.value; });
```

Comment: Why doing :checked check twice. Also he has no ids on checkboxes. .attr('name') should work.

Comment: @AamirAfridi: Where do you see `:checked` check twice? If you look again, you will see that there is actually an id on the checkboxes, but there is no name, so `attr("id")` works and `attr("name")` doesn't.

Comment: @AamirAfridi: Checking for `:checkbox` is to determine if it is a checkbox or not, and checking for `:checked` is to determine if it is checked or not. If you would to only one check, you would handle unchecked checkboxes as other elements, and they would end up in the data object anyway. As the code has to handle more than just checkboxes, both checks are needed.

Comment: if you do is(':checked') that should be enough :)  also in his first version http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/AJwXV/1/ he has name and http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/AJwXV/2/ has id for each checkbox

Comment: @AamirAfridi: That is enough if you only want to check if it's a checked checkbox, but it can't handle any other elements. Regarding the fiddles, yes I understand that you did look at an older version when you wrote the comment.

Comment: Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/AJwXV/9/ so you don't have to loop through all elements and make sure before checking for is.(':checked') of each element, the elment should be a checkbox. Not sure what exactly is he asking in question but I am sure he don't want the buttons value in JSON. All he need is the list of checked checkboxes.

Comment: @AamirAfridi: In the example in the question the submit button is included. Some server code uses the value from the button to determine why the request comes, in that case it has to be included for the server code to work.

Comment: In that case, yes you are right but still you can simply it like. check http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/N2P2c/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/N2P2c/1/ :P

Comment: Very impressive, @Guffa.  +1 - you read it "between lines" very well.  Yes, that's my purpose on including the submit and its value.  Basically - as a server-side programmer, I want my servers to know exactly where all `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` came from as part of "jail" process before accepting values to "enter" my server for database storage.

Answer (score 0):

You're arbitrarily assigning the value of all inputs, you're not actually checking the `checked` state.

Add a conditional line for:

```
data[input.attr("id")] = input.val();
```

Something like:

```
if (/* (input is a checkbox and checkbox is checked) or input is not a checkbox*/) {
        data[input.attr("id")] = input.val();
}
```

You also need an exception for radio buttons.

Comment: the radio part works for me and had no problem.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/JF3Qv/

Comment: No it doesn't actually, it has exactly the same problem. If you don't check any of the radio buttons they will show up with their value. If you make a group, the value will be the last radio button, even if it is unselected.